# How does java junit catch the error for testing?

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to java I'm trying to create the account deposit using what the junit testing below for test the account deposit with "zero" , I'm starting with deposit method  but I could not figured it out what I am missing here.

I don't understand the part that .. If I already try to catch the deposit <= 0 in my if statement , why junit still fail me ?

```
   public void testZeroDeposit()
    {   System.out.println("---testZeroDeposit");
        Account account = new AccountImpl(0);
        try {  System.out.println("---testZeroDeposit -- try");
            account.deposit(0);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  System.out.println("---testZeroDeposit -- catch");
            // Expected
        }
    }
```

my bank account plan to have deposit / balance and withdraw as follow ..

====Account.java====

```
public interface Account
{
    int id();
    long balance();
    void deposit(long amount);
    void withdraw(long amount) throws InsufficientFundsException;
}
```

======AccountImpl.java======

```
public class AccountImpl implements Account {

    private long balance;
    private int id;

    private int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public AccountImpl(int id) {
        // 
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public long balance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * deposit money ( amount ) => account balance go up 
     */
    @Override
    public void deposit(long amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ( amount <= 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Please deposit positive amount");
        }
        balance += amount;
        System.out.println("Transaction : Account " + getId() + ": deposit: $ " + amount + " new balance : $" + balance);
    }


    @Override
    public void withdraw(long amount) throws InsufficientFundsException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int id() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

===== the console result ===

**

```
**---testZeroDeposit -- try
Please deposit positive amount
Transaction : Account 0: deposit: $ 0 new balance : $0**
```

**

====junit result ====
[image]

Comment: in `try` block `fail()` will throw Assertion error. Is it the error you are getting?

Comment: You're only catching one type of exception...

Answer (score 4):

Your `deposit` method tests if the `amount` is less than or equal to zero, but all it does is print a message.  The execution of the method then continues normally, and no exception is thrown.

Your JUnit test case is expecting an `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown, and you call `fail` if it isn't thrown.  It's not thrown, so the test fails.

Instead of printing an error message in `deposit`, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.  This will make your test case succeed.

By the way, with JUnit 4 and later, the way to expect an exception to be thrown is by supplying an expected exception type in the `@Test` annotation.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
```

Then you don't have to perform a try/catch just to fail if there isn't an exception.  JUnit will perform that logic for you.

Comment: I am not allowed to change what in junit though. how can I achieve this solving something in the AccountImpl.java  , sorry i am really new to java .. hope this is not too stupid to ask.

Comment: @JPC I have already stated the necessary change in `AccountImpl` - throw the exception; don't print an error message.  That should get your test case to work regardless of how you are having JUnit test for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `expected` parameter on the annotation to mark to the test that it is a success to get the exception, and a failure to not get it.

```
import org.junit.*;

/**
 * JUnit Expected Exception Test
 * @author mkyong
 *
 */
public class JunitTest2 {

    @Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)  
    public void divisionWithException() {  
      int i = 1/0;
    }  

}
```

[Stolen from mykong.](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/)

Comment: I am not allowed to change what in junit though. how can I achieve this solving something in the AccountImpl.java

Comment: Well, the test is looking for you to throw an exception.  You're just printing an output line.